# How to Get More Stable Notifications in Xiaomi MI 2 Band when Pebble and Android 6?

Tags: xiaomi, pebble, gadgetbridge, mi-band-2

Known situation: [How to force reset the Band?](https://www.reddit.com/r/miband/comments/3e94dj/how_to_force_reset_the_band/) when using Pebble smartwatch too
Complications: Phone MI app cannot connect to the band, I do not get any notifications about my emails, ...

Phone: Samsung Galaxy S4
Phone OS: Cyanogenmod 13 (Temasek's unofficial Rom)
Activity band: Xiaomi MI Band 2 (unstable here)
Smart watch: Pebble Classic 1 (stable notifications here)
Pebble firmware: 3.12.2 (newest 9.8.2016)
Pebble hardware: V3R3

Comment: The Mi:2 is quite new, so it might not yet be mature. But you could try an alternative Android app for that: [Gadgetbridge](https://github.com/Freeyourgadget/Gadgetbridge) has [Initial support for Mi Band 2](https://github.com/Freeyourgadget/Gadgetbridge/issues/323) and always welcomes testers. I'm using it with my Pebble Time Steel and am really satisfied. If you're willing to give it a try, you can [install the app from F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=nodomain.freeyourgadget.gadgetbridge).

Comment: Check the [Wiki](https://github.com/Freeyourgadget/Gadgetbridge/wiki) first, Masi :) Tapping a Gadget's entry usually opens the list of apps installed on it. Try tap-and-hold (long-Tap) the entry, that gives you a context menu. As for uninstalling the original apps: nobody forces you to do that. I'd leave them installed for the moment; once you find you no longer need them, you can still uninstall them. I've never used (or even installed) the original Pebble app, I found it too intrusive ;)

Comment: Have you checked with the wiki, as I recommended? Sorry, but I can't guide you through the entire project step-by-step here ;) There's e.g. a [Getting started with Pebble](https://github.com/Freeyourgadget/Gadgetbridge/wiki/Pebble-Getting-Started) (as mentioned, for the Mi the wiki still has huge gaps – and I cannot help with that either as I have none).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mi:2 is quite new, so it might not yet be mature. But you could try an alternative Android app for that: **[Gadgetbridge](https://github.com/Freeyourgadget/Gadgetbridge)** has [Initial support for Mi Band 2](https://github.com/Freeyourgadget/Gadgetbridge/issues/323) and always welcomes testers. I'm using it with my Pebble Time Steel and am really satisfied. If you're willing to give it a try, you can [install the app from F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=nodomain.freeyourgadget.gadgetbridge).

A few things to note on *Gadgetbridge:*

- GB is privacy focused. Thus it e.g. doesn't request the Internet permission (and probably never will), which means that watch apps/faces requiring that won't be able to do the corresponding jobs unless they come with a companion app. However, there are plans for an [internet enabled addon](https://github.com/Freeyourgadget/Gadgetbridge/issues/302) which might add that feature for those who want it.
- at the moment, multiple Gadgets cannot be connected to GB at the same time. Again, this is something [being worked on](https://github.com/Freeyourgadget/Gadgetbridge/issues/305).

Gadgetbridge is a quite active project, so don't give up if you miss something. Also, it has a pretty good [Wiki](https://github.com/Freeyourgadget/Gadgetbridge/wiki) you should make sure to check (and you're welcome to contribute to that: I've meanwhile covered most of the Pebble part – but not having a Mi I had to leave the gaps open in that section ;)

Comment: How do you manage the installation of Pebble Apps in your Pebble?

Comment: See: [Pebble Watchfaces](https://github.com/Freeyourgadget/Gadgetbridge/wiki/Pebble-Watchfaces) (apps on your Pebble (aka Watchfaces), where to find, how to use/manage, known issues/limitations) ;) There is no market integrated, if you mean that. I usually download apps manually (link in the wiki – important: the `dev_settings=true` in the URL, or the download link won't be shown).

Answer (score 1):

Do steps as described in Izzy's [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/154416/9897) and particularly in Gadgetbridge's [wiki](https://github.com/Freeyourgadget/Gadgetbridge/wiki) where the main point is (1). 
I found out the stability increases significantly in using both systems at the same time by

1. Have the latest firmware in Pebble, disconnect Pebble official application, use *Gadgetbridge* of F-Droid to connect to Pebble
2. Use Mi Band's official application to use it.

Result: both systems can be controlled once again; Pebble's official application is complicating for some reason with Mi Band's software.

Comment: Thanks, Masi – I didn't know about the side effects the official Pebble app has on MiBand. Hope you like Gadgetbridge – and maybe you can help feeding the Wiki on MiBand topics (feeding the Wiki was my way to say thanks for the great work the GB people do ;)

Comment: @Izzy I updated the wiki here https://github.com/Freeyourgadget/Gadgetbridge/wiki/Mi-Band-Compatibility-Issues in the section *Pebble*.

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot! Feel encouraged to continue – and enjoy Gadgetbridge :)