# How to Put Mi Band 2 to Silent Mode Now with Android Phone?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, bugs, xiaomi, mi-band-2

Situation: to put Xiaomi Mi Band 2 to Silent mode when configuration with two Internet Gadgets in connection to Android 6 phone as described [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/154407/how-to-get-more-stable-notifications-in-xiaomi-mi-2-band-when-pebble-and-android/154427#154427); **Android's own silent mode does not work as expected with the internet gadgets**

I experience much duplicate notifications when using Pebble and Mi Band 2 at the same time. I can put Pebble to silent mode easily but not Mi Band 2. DND is only time specific there in the Mi Fit's settings but not now.

I cannot use Gadgetbridge for the task because I already use it for Pebble and it only supports one device at the moment.

Phone: Samsung Galaxy S4
Phone OS: Cyanogenmod 13 (Temasek's unofficial Rom)
Activity band: Xiaomi MI Band 2
Smart watch: Pebble Classic 1
Pebble firmware: 3.12.2 (newest 9.8.2016)
Pebble hardware: V3R3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Playstore

- Install the application *[Do Not Disturb](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cabooze.buzzoff)*. It puts all your internet gadgets and your phone to silent when you want in the tab *Now*. 
  Android's own silent mode does not work as expected.

F-Droid

- ...

Get a new phone

- Oneplus 2's hardware button of the left-hand-side at the top position seems to override those notifications too

Comment: Could you please include a link to the application (Playstore/F-Droid preferred)? A search for "do not disturb" yields more than 300 app results, so it's not clear which app you refer to.